# Nuxt not adding bodyAttr on refresh / ssr

Tags: vue.js, vuex, server-side-rendering, nuxt.js

I have the following code in one of my layouts.

```
bodyAttrs: {
    class: this.$store.state.user.theme + '-scheme'
}
```

unfortunately, i am using an old bootstrap theme css. I DO NOT want to redo it as such i have to figure out some work arounds.

The theme color for the bootstrap theme attaches itself to the body tag. Unfortunately the body tag is a no no in nuxt.

What i have noticed is, that upon refresh the page is rendered with the base state value.

example :

```
//store/index.js <- not modular
var state = () => ({
   user: {
    id: 0,
    avatar: 'default.jpg',
    status: 'offline',
    nickname: 'Guest',
    admin: false,
    theme: 'brownish' //-> this is the value
  }
})
```

The entire page renders with the users details but the theme variable is not placed into the render. If i go to another page(ajax routing), the page is updated with the correct color.

Essentially the page loads brown and then on subsequent pages it will load blue. If the page is refreshed then the color reverts to brown and then on subsequent pages it will turn blue again.

How can i get the SSR to display the correct bodyAttr?

I am using vuex-persistedstate and cookies both are client side
The nuxt server does not have any sessions as this is handled on a separate domain(api)

Comment: I have the same issue. I opened an issue about this today: https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/5853

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find a pure vuejs way to do this so i made a fix.

This is technically a bad idea as it is directly modifying the DOM which is a no-no in vue. However, vue doesnt use reactivity on the body tag. Therefore i think it is fairly safe to use. Also, using vuex-presistedstate will ensure that vue set the proper state variable on subsequent loads..

//This is layouts/default.vue

```
head() {
 return {
  bodyAttrs: {
    class: this.$store.state.user.theme + '-scheme'
  }
 }
},
mounted() {
 window.onNuxtReady(() => {
  document.body.className = this.$store.state.user.theme + '-scheme'
 })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the cookies based version of vuex-persistedstate? [Customize Storage](https://github.com/robinvdvleuten/vuex-persistedstate#customize-storage)
Remember to enable the ssr mode for the plugin in nuxt.config.js

Comment: Using the local storage version. Either way the cookie/local storage is client side and the SSR is server side which is the problem

Comment: Cookies can be passed to server side (check this [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cookie-universal-nuxt) for the universal library) but I haven't tried with vuex-persistedstate. If you havn't solved, I will try tomorrow.